# Curvature expression using Levi-Civita symbol

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus, curvature

I've seen the following expression to curvature tensor
$$R^j_{ab}=2 \partial_{[a}\Gamma^j_{b]}+ \epsilon_{jkl}\Gamma^k_a \Gamma^l_b $$
both on Thiemann (equation $4.2.31$) and Rovelli's (equation $3.84$) respectivly on their LQG books. Thiemann only says that this relation with covariante derivative is given by
$$[D_a,D_b]v_j=R_{abjl} v^l=\epsilon_{jkl} R^k_{ab} v^l. $$

But I didn't understood where this comes from, if it was defined this way or what. I also did not found this expression anywhere else.

How can I manage to show this expression is equivalent to the usual one
$$R^l_{ijk}= 2 \partial_{[i}\Gamma^l_{j]k}+ \big(\Gamma^m_{jk}\Gamma^l_{im}-\Gamma^l_{jm}\Gamma^m_{ik}\big) \qquad ?$$

In order to do that I think we might to use the Levi-Civita property:
$$ \epsilon_{ijn}\epsilon^{pqn}=\delta_i^p\delta_j^q-\delta_i^q\delta_j^p.$$
I'm not sure that's the way, but using this it's not hard to show that
$$ \Gamma^m_{jk}\Gamma^l_{im}-\Gamma^l_{jm}\Gamma^m_{ik} =\big(\Gamma^l_{pm}\Gamma^m_{qk}\big)\epsilon_{ijn}\epsilon^{pqn}.$$
and that's it, I'm suck from here. I'd appreciate any help or reference. Also it might be important to know that we are in three dimensions and using $\mathfrak{so}(3)$-valued connections.

[image: Image from Thiemann's book]

Comment: Some typos in the indices on the first expression

Comment: Thanks, already corrected